# MS Access - not sure if my way to get percentiles is alright

Tags: ms-access, percentile

I tried to get percentiles of a column in MS Access via SQL, but couldn't find a way to achieve it (probably it is way easier than I think it is). So I wrote a function that used Recordsets instead of a single SQL query. But still I am unsure whether this way is ok or I should go and still try to get the percentiles via SQL query?

```
Sub foo()

    Dim sCol As String, sTable As String
        sCol = "col1"
        sTable = "perc_test"

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & sCol & " FROM " & sTable & " ORDER BY " & sCol, dbOpenSnapshot)

    With rs
    If Not (.EOF And .BOF) Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        For q = 0 To 0.9999999999999 Step 1 / 10
            Debug.Print getpercentile(rs, sCol, q)
        Next q
    End If
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub


Function getpercentile(ByRef rs As Recordset, ByVal sCol As String, ByVal dPerc As Double) As Double

    Dim dReturn As Double

    Dim lCount As Long
    lCount = rs.RecordCount

    With rs
    If Not (.EOF And .BOF) Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        .Move (Round(lCount * dPerc, 0))
        dReturn = rs.Fields(sCol).Value
    End If
    End With

    getpercentile = dReturn

End Function
```

So far it works as intended. Any improvements to make it faster and/or saver (regarding errors)?

Comment: what is your goal? also why two functions accessing and looping the same record-set?

Comment: Provide a little bit of sample data (`col1` and desired outcome). I feel like there may be an easier way, but the code is not that intuitive.